# Once there is error, webpack-dev-server will stop working and browser is not auto updated again even after error is fixed

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I am using Webpack 5 to build a static HTML boilerplate. Everything works fine, Webpack is compiled successfully and browser is updated whenever I make change to HTML, SCSS/CSS or JS file in my source code.

The problem happens if there is error in the code, WDS will stop working and browser will display an error message in the console, for example:
[image]

Even after I fix the error and Webpack says that it is compiled successfully, WDS still does not work and the browser keeps stuck at the error. I have to reload the browser manually to make it work again.

Can anyone please help me? What should I do to make browser updated again after error is fixed?

I found the same question [webpack-dev-server stops compiling after a syntax error, requires restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62395604/webpack-dev-server-stops-compiling-after-a-syntax-error-requires-restart), but there is no proper answer to it so I have to ask another one.

This is my `webpack.common.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');

// Prepare plugins
const plugins = [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: './style/main.css?v=[contenthash]',
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
    inject: 'body',
    filename: 'index.html',
    minify: {
      minifyJS: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyURLs: true,
    },
  }),
];
// Create more HtmlWebpackPlugin
const files = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve('.', 'src/pages'), 'utf8');
files.forEach((file) => {
  const page = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: `src/pages/${file}`,
    inject: 'body',
    filename: `pages/${file}`,
    minify: {
      minifyJS: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyURLs: true,
    },
  });
  plugins.push(page);
});

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/scripts/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('.', 'build'),
    filename: './js/bundle.js?v=[contenthash]',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s?css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-hot-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'import-glob-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|woff|eot|ttf|woff2)$/,
        // use: 'url-loader',
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader', // export HTML as string. HTML is minimized when the compiler demands.
        options: {
          sources: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins,
};
```

This is my `webpack.dev.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const StylelintPlugin = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve('.', 'src'), // source of static assets
    port: 1802, // port to run dev-server
    hot: true, // hot reload
    watchContentBase: true,
    // open: true, // immediately open browser to show localhost:1802 when start script
  },
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin({}),
    new StylelintPlugin({ fix: true }),
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ onlyOnError: true }),
  ],
});
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "static-web-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple boilerplate for developing static web projects",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "cross-env ENV=development webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress",
    "start:prod": "npm run build && serve build",
    "build": "cross-env ENV=production webpack --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --stats-error-details"
  },
  "author": "Hau Pham",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "serve": "^12.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.4",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-stylelint": "^13.1.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss": "^1.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.19.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.41.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of research, I have found the solution. According to [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/3405#issuecomment-856798505) on `webpack-dev-server` github page, updating `webpack-dev-server` to version 4 should fix this. I tried and it did fix the issue!

*(At the time of this answer, the newest version 4 is `4.0.0-beta.3`)*